# Order By count(*) from other table in yii 2

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have 2 table: videos and likes
video table has fields: id, title ..
likes table has fields: id, video_id, user_id

I would like to get the 10 most like videos.
I can do it in sql by command:

```
SELECT videos.*, COUNT( likes.video_id ) AS countlike  
FROM videos LEFT JOIN likes ON videos.id = likes.video_id  
GROUP BY videos.id  
ORDER BY countlike DESC  
Limit 10
```

How can i implement it in ActiveRecord with yii 2

I would greatly appreciate with any help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should create ActiveRecord class for `video` and `likes` tables to make things easier.

The aim is to create the two following classes `class Video extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord` and `class Likes extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord`.

To do it easily, you should look at gii utility which will do it for you (available at yourdomain/gii/model). Fill the form for both your tables and you will be done.

Then you should be able to write your request:

```
$query = Video::find()
       ->select(['video.*', 'COUNT(likes.video_id) AS countlike'])
       ->join('LEFT JOIN', Likes::tableName(), 'videos.id=likes.video_id')
       ->groupBy('videos.id')
       ->orderBy(['countlike' => SORT_DESC])
       ->limit(10);
$data = $query->all();
```

In my opinion there is nothing magical in using ActiveRecord for complex requests. But it may avoid errors.

I highly recommend reading ActiveQuery documentation for more info about parameters of above methods. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Mat, Can you help me? I have applied same query in one my logic. But i am not getting the value of "countlike" in $data response. And also i am not getting any error can you please help in this scenario.

Comment: How to extract countlike from $data object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
videos.id
)id, videos . * , count( likes.id ) as count
FROM `videos`
LEFT JOIN likes ON videos.id = likes.video_id
ORDER BY count DESC
```